# Select the same column multiple times

Tags: sql, select

hope someone can help. I have two tables:

```
Users
  -UserID
  -UserName

UsersType
  -UserTypeID
  -UserID
```

Possible values for UsersTypeID is 1 to 6. In that scenario Users may have multiple types and I need to retrieve a distinct row for each user with the columns described below.

```
UserName - Type1 - Type2 - Type3 - Type4
Joe            0       1       1       0
```

In this scenario, Joe has two different User type (2,3)

This might be easy as pie but I have been working around this for so long that I am clueless. Can some one help please.

Comment: lol, 6 answers already. Too many cooks...

Comment: You might want to rethink your strategy for querying those values.  Since you don't know how many types a user might have, pulling them into a single row is going to be problematic. It might be better to simply query the types and load them into your application. That being said, Thomas' answer below looks like a winner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard crosstab output which you should be able to google. Although not recommended in SQL you can do something like:

```
Select Users.Username
    , Max( Case When UsersType.UserTypeId = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Type1
    , Max( Case When UsersType.UserTypeId = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Type2
    , Max( Case When UsersType.UserTypeId = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Type3
    , Max( Case When UsersType.UserTypeId = 4 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Type4
From Users
        Join UsersType
            On UsersType.UserId = Users.UserId
Group By Users.UserName
```

(Updated to Max instead of Min)

Comment: I just tested this. Doesn't work. At best you get a row for each user with 4 zeros, or 3 zeros and a 1 (i.e. only shows one type membership).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.[UserName]
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 1'
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 2 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 2'
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 3 THEN 3 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 3'
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 4 THEN 4 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 4'
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 5 THEN 5 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 5'
    , AVG(CASE WHEN UT.[UserTypeID] IS 6 THEN 6 ELSE NULL END) AS N'Type 6'
FROM [Users] U
    INNER JOIN [UserType] UT ON UT.[UserID] = U.[UserID]
GROUP BY U.[UserName]
ORDER BY U.[UserName]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pivot you can do

```
SELECT 
    UserName, 
    [1] as 'type1', 
    [2] as 'type2', 
    [3] as 'type3', 
    [4] as 'type4', 
    [5] as 'type5', 
    [6] as 'type6'
FROM (
        SELECT 
            UserName, 
            userTypeId 
        FROM 
            users LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersType
            ON users.userId = usersType.userid
    ) AS src
PIVOT (
    count(userTypeId) FOR userTypeId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]) ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

The known, limited number of UserTypeID values makes this (relatively) straightforward strategy possible.  This looks hairy, but as long as your indexes are good the performance should be good.

```
Select U.UserName, Case When UT1.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type1,   
    Case When UT2.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type2,
    Case When UT3.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type3, 
    Case When UT4.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type4, 
    Case When UT5.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type5, 
    Case When UT6.UserType Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End As Type6, 
From Users As U
    Left Join UsersType As UT1 On U.UserID = UT1.UserID
    Left Join UsersType As UT2 On U.UserID = UT2.UserID     
    Left Join UsersType As UT3 On U.UserID = UT3.UserID     
    Left Join UsersType As UT4 On U.UserID = UT4.UserID     
    Left Join UsersType As UT5 On U.UserID = UT5.UserID     
    Left Join UsersType As UT6 On U.UserID = UT6.UserID     
Where UT1.UserTypeID = 1 And UT2.UserTypeID = 2
    And UT3.UserTypeID = 3 And UT4.UserTypeID = 4
    And UT5.UserTypeID = 5 And UT6.UserTypeID = 6
```

You would often come up with an alternate strategy if you want the ability to add UserTypes and still have this work.  In this case, you'll need a udf or stored procedure to construct the query and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a LEFT JOIN.  Try something like this

```
SELECT
UserName
U1.UserTypeID AS Type1
U2.UserTypeID AS Type2
U3.UserTypeID AS Type3
U4.UserTypeID AS Type4
FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN UsersType U1 ON U.UserID  = U1.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 1
LEFT JOIN UsersType U2 ON U.UserID  = U2.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 2
LEFT JOIN UsersType U3 ON U.UserID  = U3.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 3
LEFT JOIN UsersType U4 ON U.UserID  = U4.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 4
```

If you want the rows to just return true or false then I would do this(it is SQL Server specific):

```
SELECT
UserName
CASE WHEN U1.UserTypeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Type1
CASE WHEN U2.UserTypeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Type2
CASE WHEN U3.UserTypeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Type3
CASE WHEN U4.UserTypeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Type4
FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN UsersType U1 ON U.UserID  = U1.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 1
LEFT JOIN UsersType U2 ON U.UserID  = U2.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 2
LEFT JOIN UsersType U3 ON U.UserID  = U3.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 3
LEFT JOIN UsersType U4 ON U.UserID  = U4.UserID AND UserTypeID  = 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone, Thomas bring me THE solution I was looking for... Kudos

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly the result set you are looking for the query is ugly and not very scalable (for example, if you had 100 usertypes) but here you go

```
  select 
     u.username,
     isnull(ut1.Usertypeid,0) as Type1,
     isnull(ut2.Usertypeid,0) as Type2,
     isnull(ut3.Usertypeid,0) as Type3,
     isnull(ut4.Usertypeid,0) as Type4,
     isnull(ut5.Usertypeid,0) as Type5,
     isnull(ut6.Usertypeid,0) as Type6

    from 
        users u
    left outer join 
        userstype ut1 on u.userid = ut1.userid and ut1.usertypeid = 1
    left outer join 
        userstype ut2 on u.userid = ut2.userid and ut2.usertypeid = 2
    left outer join 
        userstype ut3 on u.userid = ut3.userid and ut3.usertypeid = 3
    left outer join 
        userstype ut4 on u.userid = ut4.userid and ut4.usertypeid = 4
    left outer join 
        userstype ut5 on u.userid = ut5.userid and ut5.usertypeid = 5
    left outer join 
        userstype ut6 on u.userid = ut6.userid and ut6.usertypeid = 6
```

**EDIT**

Once you've got to your 10th user type hopefully common sense will kick in (hopefully before the 10th) and you'll think to yourself *this can't go on!*

When that happens you'd be better off querying like this

```
select 
     u.username,
     ut..Usertypeid
    from 
        users u
    left outer join 
        userstype ut
    on u.userid = ut.userid
```

You would then get a result set that looks like

```
  Username | UserTypeID
  ---------------------
  Joe      | 3
  Joe      | 4
```

which you'll have to loop through at your client end BUT is a lot kinder to your database server and your sanity!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're stating there will only be 6 values for the type, I can suggest using subqueries:

```
SELECT  UserName
        ,(
            SELECT  CONVERT(bit, COUNT(UserTypeID))
            FROM    UsersType AS ut
            WHERE   ut.UserID = u.UserID
                    AND ut.UserTypeID = 1
        ) AS Type1
        ,(
            SELECT  CONVERT(bit, COUNT(UserTypeID))
            FROM    UsersType AS ut
            WHERE   ut.UserID = u.UserID
                    AND ut.UserTypeID = 2
        ) AS Type2
        ,...
FROM    Users AS u
```

Comment: Subqueries become slow because you will be doing a table scan every for every row.